# PopIn from center

Tags: css, animation, styled-components

I want my `StyledModalWrapper` to animate `scale()`.

My StyledComponent has this properties:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
max-width: ${(props:IModal) => props.width};
min-height: auto;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
animation: ${(props:IModal) => props.closing ? popOut : popIn} .3s linear;
```

The animation:

```
0% {
    transform: scale(0);
}
80% {
    transform: scale(1.25);
}
100% {
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

In this case the box is scaling perfect only the positioning isn't.

I tried adding

```
0% {
    transform: scale(0) translate(100%, 100%);
}
80% {
    transform: scale(1.25) translate(25%, 25%);
}
100% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(50%, 50%);
}
```

In this case it swipes with a curve.

The center of the box should always stay in the middle of the parent.
The parent has a `width/height` of `100vw/100vh`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `transform`, this is your friend: `transform-origin`

It allows you to change to transform position from left/top to anywhere else.
In your case it's likely `center` you need.

MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just added `transform-origin: -50%, -50%;` to the StyledComponent and added `transform-origin: center;` to the animation. But the box is'nt in the center anymore.

Comment: Changed `-50%, -50%` to `-50% -50%`. But that wasn't it.

Comment: This happens because the transform origin is causing all transform properties to be executed on that position. This will not be problem for things like scale but might be a problem for the translate you added.
You can try positioning the element in the center without using `transform` properties i.e. with negative margins or any of the other methods for centering an HTML element with CSS. That should prevent the element from goign offset before / during or after transform happens. Hope that helps.